# How to use SoxController Class In ffmpeg library In android ? Any Example

Tags: android

Having Problems in Using SoxController Class . . Can Any body give me the example of trimaudio function in SoxController Class . . .

Answer (score 0):

Let try this one,, I think it's perfect for you because I tested already. it works well

```
/**
 * Trim File Wave
 */
public class TrimFileWave extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    private ProgressDialogUtil progressDialogUtil;
    private Context            context;

    public TrimFileWave(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        progressDialogUtil = new ProgressDialogUtil(context, R.string.progressing);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialogUtil.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        startTrimFile();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        progressDialogUtil.dismiss();
    }

    private void startTrimFile() {
        File fileAppRoot = new File(context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir);
        try {
            SoxController sxCon = new SoxController(context, fileAppRoot, new ShellUtils.ShellCallback() {
                @Override
                public void shellOut(String shellLine) {
                    DebugUtil.log(new Exception(), shellLine);
                }

                @Override
                public void processComplete(int exitValue) {
                    DebugUtil.log(new Exception(), exitValue);
                }
            });
            double length = sxCon.getLength(MyApplication.FILE_NAME_RECORDED_WAVE);
            DebugUtil.log(new Exception(), "[length]" + length);
            // sxCon.trimAudio(MyApplication.FILE_MERGE_WAVE, 0, length);
            // Type {"q", "h", "t", "l", "p"}
            sxCon.fadeAudio(MyApplication.FILE_MERGE_WAVE, "t", 0, length, 1);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            DebugUtil.logInfo(new Exception(), e.toString());
        }
    }

}
```